# display:grid CSS3 lay-out is not working

Tags: html, css, display

I'm trying to make an HTML layout with `display:grid` but it is not working. I want to have a layout with 2 columns and 3 rows. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the simplified HTML code I use. I added a printscreen to show the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            #Main {
                display:grid;
                grid-columns:75% 25%;
                grid-rows:20% 70% 10%;
            }

            #Main > header {
                grid-column: 1;
                grid-row:1;
                grid-column-span:2;
                background-color:red;
            }

            #Main > section {
                grid-column:1;
                grid-row:2;
                background-color:yellow;
            }

            #Main > aside {
                grid-column:2;
                grid-row:2;
                grid-row-span:2;
                background-color:green;             
            }

            #Main > footer {
                grid-column: 1;
                grid-row:3;
                grid-column-span:2;
                background-color:blue;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Main">

            <header>
                header
            </header>

            <section>
                section
            </section>

            <aside>
                aside
            </aside>  

            <footer>
                footer
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `grid` has not been implemented yet, so no browser support it (well IE10 does, kind of, prefixed)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. It is strange they put the grid function in de book Exam Ref 070-480 while it is not implemented yet